# TeeChart Label, when screen density > 1, wrong positioned on Y-Axis on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, teechart

TeeChart Label, when screen density > 1, wrong positioned on Y-Axis on Android
and it gets worse the with density.

the "funny" thing is that it is the "displacement" or "depth" from the 3D model that i cant get rid off.

the same code on the iphone has no problems.

somehow it seams that Aspect.View3D = false does not do the same on android that it does on iphone.

I am using the Styles.Area()

a small ss of my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGXPJ.jpg

edit: the chart code

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Drawing;

namespace App2
{
    [Activity(Label = "App2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart(this);
        Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Area area = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Area();
        tChart1.Series.Add(area);
        tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Visible = true;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.AutomaticMaximum = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.AutomaticMinimum = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Maximum = 140;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Minimum = 20;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(40, " 40");
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(60, " 60");
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(80, " 80");
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(100, "100");
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(120, "[dB]");

        SetContentView(tChart1); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here and also let us know in which kind of Android device this problem occurs? You can post your files at www.steema.net/upload/

Comment: it is currently not posible for me to give you the hole project. i have put the chart code in an edit, is this usefull? 
And the device i am using right now is an Nexus5 with density 3

Comment: we don't need your complete production project but a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://www.sscce.org/). That should suffice, thanks.

Comment: the upload page cannot take the 13mb file, that is the scrubbed down project. i have edited the code in the question to the "stand alone"

Comment: Just fixed the bug. Are you interested in a test assembly with the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. I have added it to [Steema Software's bug tracking system](http://bugs.teechart.net/) ([Bug #1128](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1128)). It has already been fixed. If you are interested I can provide with test assembly with the fix. An evaluation version can be downloaded [here](http://tinyurl.com/mqdeaad).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! 
When can we expect an updated (not eval ;) ) .dll ? My version is bought at the Xamarin strore i think.

Comment: @Wind please send an email to sales@steema.com with your license number mentioning this thread and we will provide a non-eval assembly.